# Saving a plot as JPEG

Tags: r, export, radix, axis-labels

I have a problem with a simple plot in base R. The y label of this plot is not properly displayed

[image]

I tried changing the plot size and the text size but the y label always remains slightly outside the frame.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to customise the position of the labels relative to the axes?

Comment: It could be a problem with plot margins. Check out par(mar, mgp, las) : http://rfunction.com/archives/1302

Comment: Did you try increasing the left margin? It would be easier to help if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)